# Differences in variables for PowerShell 2.0 and 3.0

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a script that uses `Invoke-Command` against a group of webservers.  Some of the servers have different versions of PowerShell installed.  I'm having to write the scriptblock so that it checks the PowerShell version and uses older commands if it detects that PowerShell 2.0 is installed.  Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with PowerShell 2.0...  Here's the problem I'm running into:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration    
$sites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\sites
```

In PowerShell 3 I can just say `$bindings = $sites.Bindings.Collection.BindingInformation` (which will contain the IP and port of the application pool).  However, in PowerShell 2 if I try the same thing, calling `$bindings` returns nothing.  If I call `$sites` in PowerShell 2 I still get back a table of information, but `$sites.Name` for example will not return anything.

**Edit:**

I've figured out a way to get the data I want by using:

```
$sites | select -Expand Bindings |
    select -Expand Collection |
    select -Expand BindingInformation
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: [Member enumeration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/) was added with PowerShell v3. In earlier versions you must enumerate members of array elements yourself, e.g. via `Select-Object -Expand property` or `ForEach-Object {$_.property}`.